# assigning slices to strings

Tags: python, string, slice

I've looked around for an answer/solution for this question for a bit, as it seems like it should have been asked already. But I have failed to find anything about reassigning a `slice`. I'm doing one of the quizzes for the online code teacher Treehouse, and they have given me this question/assignment:

> I need you to create a new function for me.
>   This one will be named **sillycase** and it'll take a single string as an argument.
>   **sillycase** should return the same string *but* the first half should be lowercased and the second half should be uppercased.
>   For example, with the string "Treehouse", **sillycase** would return "treeHOUSE".
>   Don't worry about rounding your halves, but remember that indexes should be 
>   integers. You'll want to use the **int()** function or integer division, **//.**

I've worked off of other people's questions and gotten this far:

```
def sillycase(example):
    begining = example[:len(example) // 2]
    end = example[len(example) // 2:]
    begining.lower()
    end.upper()
    example = begining + end
    return example
```

I'm not sure why that is wrong, but when I run it with example being `"Treehouse"`, it returns `"Treehouse"`. If not clear yet my question is how to get the first half of a `string` lowercased, and the second half uppercased.

Answer (score 1):

The methods `.lower()` and `.upper()` for strings return a new string and don't work in-place. The following should work which adds the new strings returned by `lower` and `upper` directly:

```
def sillycase(example):
    beginning = example[:len(example) // 2]
    end = example[len(example) // 2:]
    example = beginning.lower() + end.upper()
    return example

sillycase('treehouse')   # 'treeHOUSE'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign `.lower()` and `.upper()` to the variables, for example:

```
begining = begining.lower()
end = end.upper()
example = begining + end
```

or in your case:

```
def sillycase(example):
    begining = example[:len(example) // 2].lower()
    end = example[len(example) // 2:].upper()
    example = begining + end
    return example
```

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable! When you do

```
begining.lower()
end.upper()
```

`begining` and `end` are not changed , they just simply return you the lower and uppercase strings respectively. So in order to get the result you are expecting do something like this

```
begining = begining.lower()
end = end.upper()
```